# c++ read config file parameters using GetPrivateProfileString

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, configuration-files

I have a win32 console application in C++, Visual Studio 2012. I cannot get the config parameter from the ini file. I tried different possibilities with file path,like placing the .ini file in source folder, write the full path to is, placing in the folder with generated .exe file. The output on the console after executing of the .exe file is 0 or (null) for string in every case. What I am doing wrong? How can I read the parameters?

```
v1:
LPCTSTR path = L".\\config.ini";
TCHAR protocolChar[32];
int port = GetPrivateProfileString(_T("PORT"), _T("SETTINGS"), _T(""), protocolChar, 32, path);
printf("***%d***\n", port);

v2:
int port = GetPrivateProfileInt(_T("PORT"), _T("SETTINGS"), 0, _T("config.ini"));
```

config.ini contains:

```
[SETTINGS]
USER_NUM_MAX = 256  ; Maximum number of users
PORT = 8080;
```

Comment: printing an `int` with `%s` would be one problem. And you're sure the file is in the *current working directory* of the process? if running from the IDE, you realize the default CWD is where the *project* file resides (the vcprojx file), right?

Comment: oh, as I have different parameters I haven't written here the right type. For int i use %d.
Yes, I have ini file in the folder with ProjName.vcxproj , ProjName.vcxproj.filter, ProjName.aps, ProjName.rc. is it right? I placed the ini file in every folder now :). I doesn't work.

Comment: If its in the same folder as the vcprojx file, its the right one. Perhaps verify you can even open the file. (std::ifstream)

Comment: it is good idea, but with #include <fstream> it doesn't compile.

Comment: odd? what kinda C++ compiler can't `#include <fstream>` ? Lemme guess, this code is in a .c file.

Comment: yes, it is c. file. It is so crazy, cause I have problem not only with this issue. with select function as well. It is a homework from university and all what Im trying, nothing works. What would you suggest to handle this .c file and other libraries and function properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oups, under Windows hitting a ini file in not that easy. In both tries (v1 and v2), you look for the file in *current* directory and then in `Windows` directory but not in the directory where the executable file is.

The easy way is to put all ini files under Windows directory. If you find cleaner to have the ini file along with the exe one, you have some more work to do :

- find the executable file full path
- replace the `exe` end with `ini`
- use that full path to get access to your private ini file

To get the name of the executable file, simply use `GetModuleFileName` with a NULL `HMODULE` :

```
LPCTSTR getExecPath() {
    DWORD len = 64;
    for (;;) {
        LPTSTR fileName = new TCHAR[len];
        if (len == ::GetModuleFileName(NULL, fileName, len)) {
            delete fileName;
            len *= 2;
        }
        else {
            return fileName;
        }
    }
}
```

or if you prefere to directly get the ini file name :

```
LPCTSTR getIniName() {
    DWORD len = 4;
    for (;;) {
        LPTSTR fileName = new TCHAR[len];
        if (len == ::GetModuleFileName(NULL, fileName, len)) {
            delete fileName;
            len *= 2;
        }
        else {
            ::lstrcpy(fileName + lstrlen(fileName) - 3, "ini");
            return fileName;
        }
    }
}
```

and to not forget to delete the file name when done since it is allocated with new ...

Edit per comment :

For reference, the windows directory may depend on windows version. But it can always be retrieved by the API function `GetWindowsDirectory`. Extract from the [reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

```
UINT WINAPI GetWindowsDirectory(
  _Out_  LPTSTR lpBuffer,
  _In_   UINT uSize
);
```

*Parameters*

- `lpBuffer [out]` *A pointer to a buffer that receives the path. This path does not end with a backslash unless the Windows directory is the root directory. For example, if the Windows directory is named Windows on drive C, the path of the Windows directory retrieved by this function is C:\Windows. If the system was installed in the root directory of drive C, the path retrieved is C:.*
- `uSize [in]` *The maximum size of the buffer specified by the lpBuffer parameter, in TCHARs. This value should be set to MAX_PATH.*

*Return value*

*If the function succeeds, the return value is the length of the string copied to the buffer, in TCHARs, not including the terminating null character.*

*If the length is greater than the size of the buffer, the return value is the size of the buffer required to hold the path.*

*If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError. **

Comment: do you mean with this sencense(The easy way is to put all ini files under Windows directory. If you find cleaner....) there are two possibilities? or I have to do these 3 steps anyway? 
my ProjectName.exe file is in folder ProjectName->Debug. is it this executable file, what you mean?

Comment: @Alexito: Yes, you have 2 possibilities : either you put the ini file in Windows directory and call it as `T"config.ini"` or you put it in the same directory as the executable and use full path as described in my answer. Reference : documentation for `GetPrivateProfileString` function *lpFileName 
The name of the initialization file. If this parameter does not contain a full path to the file, the system searches for the file in the Windows directory.*

Comment: How can I find the windows directory? I tried some, but it cannot find.

Comment: @Alexito : Post edited with references for finding the Windows directory.

Comment: Thanks! the output is just C. After I placed the config.ini inside. It doesn't read the parameters. Again I tried different variants, as presented above v1, v2, "config.ini", ".\\config.ini" etc. What could be the problem?

Comment: The output should not be C. It should be something like `C:\Windows` or `C:\Winnt`. Please use a buffer of size > 255 to avoid problems and be careful with whether TCHAR is a char (ANSI mode) or a short (UNICODE mode).

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when I updated from VS2010 to VS2012.

On VS 2010 I simply called the function with the file name of the .ini-file as argument for lpFileName ([see MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

This was not working for VS 2012 any more, so I changed to go for the complete path like this:

```
char directoryPath[MAX_PATH];
char readParameter[MAX_STR_LEN];

GetCurrentDirectory( directoryPath, MAX_PATH );

string directoryPathAsString(directoryPath);
directoryPathAsString = directoryPathAsString + "\\" + filename;

GetPrivateProfileString("section","parameter","0",readParameter,MAX_STR_LEN, directoryPathAsString.c_str());
```